# Let's Encrypt Certificate in Azure Web App for Containers with Custom Domain

Tags: azure, ssl, nginx, azure-web-app-service, lets-encrypt

My goal is to create an Azure Web App for Containers, map a custom domain to it and secure this domain with an SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt which is automatically renewed every month.

So far I have successfully configured a docker-compose for the web app:

- Nginx which handles Let's Encrypt certificate renewals and https redirections
- Web App to which Nginx proxies to

Also, I successfully mapped my domain to the Azure Web App.

But there is a problem. It seems Azure is applying some certificates on its own. When I want to use the Web App from my browser, the certificate for `*.azurewebsites.net` is served:

[image: Wrong certificate served]

**Can I somehow disable SSL for the Azure Web App for Containers so that my Nginx proxy is responsible for this or use Let's Encrypt in some other way?** I know that for the Windows-Based Web Apps there is a Let's Encrypt extension, but there is no one for Azure Web App for Containers.

Comment: I´m looking for this exactly same answer. I´ll try to solve by myself. If i do any progress i´ll write down here.

Comment: Actually, I'm now using Nginx as a reverse proxy. There is a nice derivated image of it to quickly host a (very opinionated) server using Docker Compose: [staticfloat/docker-nginx-certbot](https://github.com/staticfloat/docker-nginx-certbot/tree/master/src). The thing with these web apps is that the SSL settings are pretty much abstracted away so it's hard to change them when Microsift does not provide some settings for it.